# Is there a way to minify my angular app without using annotations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

We have a large angular app which has grown organically and now we would like to start minifying our code.

I understand the issue with minification and DI in angular and just wanted to know if there is a way to minify our app without annotating function variables. We don't want to use the annotation approach.

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Why dont you want to use the annotation approach?

Comment: You could use something like grunt-ng-annotate to do it for you, though, it may still require some changes to your code.

Comment: We are using typescript and it doesn't work well with classes etc. Further I feel its a pretty lame solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  automate the annotations prior to minification.  This way your coding style and source code does not need to change.

You can use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to achieve this easily.

1. Install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) if you don't already have it.
2. Install ng-annotate package `npm install -g ng-annotate`
3. Run ng-annotate `ng-annotate OPTIONS <file>`

Optional you can use something like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to automate this.  With these task runners you can easily concatenate your JS files into one files, run ng-annotate on the file, then minify the file. This is all with a simple command like `gulp js`

No matter what your code is, the trick it to run ng-annotate after it is translated into pure javascript but prior to the minification step.

Comment: How does ng-annotate know what functions to annotate? Or does it do this for every function?

Comment: Its smart. It will annotate Angular function, even nested function and anonymous function for things defined in routes/states.  There is a helper comment that can be added to explicitly indicate that you want a specific function annotated. If you follow standard best practices it will just work. If you have your own convention, you can configure ng-annotate to work with it. https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate#declaration-forms

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as we've buried the angular constructs away behind our own layers and do alot oh angular.instantiate etc from our di wrappers so that we can support injection Array<T> etc. I'll have a play but ideally I'd just like a minifier which will remove whitespace and comments etc

Comment: In that case, you can run uglify without mangle.  It will keep your var names the same.  Just know that ng-annotate follows references and as long as your function somehow winds up in an angular function where it needs annotation, it will annotate it.